# File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/animation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, animation, compass

I need to use animation wih compass, so I try to use like said in doc: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/animation/

I put at top of my file:

```
@import "compass/css3/animation";
```

but I have error:

```
 File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/animation.
```

I have the latest version of compass and rails-compass gem, so I don't know where is my mistake?

thx.

Comment: Is this the gem you are using? https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails

Comment: @TomKadwill yes: gem 'sass-rails', gem 'compass-rails'. I have no problem for ths moment, except this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm waiting the good solution, but pending, I use this fix: http://joshbroton.com/quick-fix-sass-mixins-for-css-keyframe-animations/

hope helpful others.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have tried this already but hopefully this helps - In the [README](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails) it says that you should import compass like so:

```
@import "compass";

@import "your_project/mixins";
@import "your_project/base";
```

Or, you should use the application.css:

```
/*
*= require styleguide_full_of_compass_stuff
*/
```

Finally the README also advises not to include compass in individual files.

Comment: Not sure if the "not to include individual file" still applies

Answer (score 0):

Try do this

```
sudo gem install compass
```

If it not help try to use this compass plugin:
https://github.com/ericam/compass-animation

to add it you should to do next steps:

1) run in console

```
gem install animation --pre
```

2) add

```
require 'animation'
```

in your config.rb

3) add

```
@import "animation";
```

in you .scss/.sass file.

--

Hope it's help you!

Cheers